# Joining and combining multiple tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Got a problem with combining data with MySQL. I have 4 tables which are relationally linked to eachother.

```
exhibitions
-id
-name
-location
-form_id

form
-id
-name

form_trans
-id
-form_id
-lang_id
-content

languages
-id
-name
-code
```

As you can notice, I link the ID's to eachother so I can make changes to any of the tables without doing things doubly. This was my query at firsthand:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, c.name 
FROM `form` a, `exhibitions` b, `languages` c, `form_trans` d 
WHERE a.id = b.form_id 
AND d.form_id = a.id 
AND d.lang_id = c.id
```

Problem with this query is that it's not taking the forms which aren't linked to any of the exhibitions. To do that, I presume to use a JOIN statement, but I cannot wrap my head around the statement I have to use. I have this but it isn't even a valid query...

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM `forms` a
OUTER JOIN `exhibitions` b ON a.id = b.form_id
```

Sorry I didn't describe what I wanted to achieve. I want to select all the forms and I want to match the Exhibition (I can match the form_id with the id of the form table) and I want to match the Language in the Language table with the form ( I do that by linking the form_trans table with the form table by using id and form_id and link the language table with the form_trans table by using the lang_id <> id relation)

Comment: Inherently linked? Um, no. That's not how sql works. The clue's in the name!

Comment: You mean NATURAL JOIN?

Comment: I've changed it to Relational...

Comment: I think the best way to progress this is to find in words or by example what you want to achieve for example: "I want to see all the exhibitions for each form". We can then help you with the query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should select all the forms even if they don't have exhibitions or translations:

```
SELECT f.id As FormId
     , f.name as FormName
     , e.name As exhibitionName
     , l.name As LanguageName
FROM `form` f
LEFT JOIN  `exhibitions` e ON(f.id = e.form_id )
LEFT JOIN `form_trans` ft ON(ft.form_id = f.id )
LEFT JOIN `languages` l ON(ft.lang_id = l.id)
```

Your mistakes:

- Using implicit joins instead of explicit ones.
- Using arbitrary aliases instead of meaningful ones.

Comment: You are a hero. You've snapped something in my head. I think I actually fully understand joins now :) This is the answer to my question!

Comment: I'm no hero, just someone with some years of experience in sql... Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, LEFT JOIN lists the entries that do not have corresponding associations with the table on the right. So in our case I guess the query would go like,

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, c.name FROM `form` a LEFT JOIN 
`exhibitions` b INNER JOIN `languages` c INNER JOIN `form_trans` d
 WHERE a.id = b.form_id AND d.form_id = a.id AND d.lang_id = c.id;
```

Haven't tested the query but this should work.

Comment: Please use line breaks when needed. your sql code might be better then the one I suggested but it's pretty damn hard to read like this.

Comment: Why is this one better than your's? Better readable or better system wise?

Comment: Now that I can see the hole thing at once, I can be bothered to read it.
It's not better then mine, in fact it's worst, since javabot is mixing 2 join styles and uses the same meaningless aliases. since you mentioned readability, the line breaks in my sql help to make it more readable by segmenting it's parts. the line breaks used here seem arbitrary and only help to see the entire sql without scrolling.

Comment: I'm lazy.. I just copied the query from the question and edited on that ;)